# Send notification to self using the Firebase framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to implement a notification test capability where a push notification is sent to the user. This was quite easy to do in Parse, and I'm trying to duplicate this functionality with the Firebase framework like so.

```
[[FIRInstanceID instanceID] getIDWithHandler:^(NSString * _Nullable identity, NSError * _Nullable error) {

            if (error) {
                [self stopWaitingForTestNotification];
            }
            else {
                NSDictionary *payloadDict = @{@"alert": @"Success, Push Notifications are working.", SMAppRemoteNotificationTestNotificationIdentifierKey: @"true"};
                [[FIRMessaging messaging] sendMessage:payloadDict to:identity withMessageID:@"test-notification" timeToLive:10];
            }
        }];
```

Some of you may not be surprised to know that this is not delivering any notifications, or errors in the console. Is this the wrong way to reference the current user, or is this even possible?

Answer (score 2):

You code above is trying to send message to server not a device, see [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/upstream)

> To send messages upstream to the server, an iOS client app composes a message and calls `sendMessage`

If you are trying to send notification from your device to your device.

1. you need a server.
2. Your iOS apps sending upstream message to server.
3. Server sending downstream message to your iOS apps.

or if you just simply want to test push notification
implement [downstream message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream) in your iOS Apps or use `pod try Firebase` and send notification from firebase console